# Message Box with Yes and No buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on Windows Phone 8, i have scenario where in the message box i am questioning the  user, So the user has to click YES or NO.

But the meassage box is having only OK and Cancel buttons, which i dont need it.

Here is my code:

```
MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure? This will delete all your data", "Attention!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted", "Done", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
```

How can i modify this to YES and NO buttons ? and also can i have 3 buttons as well with custom text on buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this custom Message Box

SLMessageBox.xaml

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="SLMessageBoxEX.SLMessageBox"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
                  xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
                  xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                  Title="SL Custom Message Box"
                  Width="320"
                  Height="150">
<controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
<controls:ChildWindow.Style>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="AlertBoxStyle" />
</controls:ChildWindow.Style>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="txtMsg"
             Width="195"
             Margin="59,22,0,22"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Background="#02FFFFFF"
             BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
             Cursor="Arrow"
             FontSize="11"
             FontWeight="SemiBold"
             IsReadOnly="True"
             SelectionBackground="#FF727272"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
             Text="SysInformation Healthcare India Pvt Ltd."
             TextAlignment="Center"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="btnYes"
                Width="65"
                Height="23"
                Margin="10,0,5,0"
                Click="OKButton_Click"
                Content="Yes"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnNo"
                Width="65"
                Height="23"
                Margin="5,0,5,0"
                Click="btnNo_Click"
                Content="No"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnCancel"
                Width="65"
                Height="23"
                Margin="5,0,5,0"
                Click="CancelButton_Click"
                Content="Cancel"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Image x:Name="imgIcon"
           Width="45"
           Height="40"
           Margin="10,20,0,20"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF434343" />
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>

</Grid>
```

SLMessageBox.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SLMessageBoxEX
{
public partial class SLMessageBox : ChildWindow
{
    public delegate void MessageBoxClosedDelegate(MessageBoxResult result);
    public event MessageBoxClosedDelegate OnMessageBoxClosed;
    public MessageBoxResult Result { get; set; }

    public SLMessageBox(string title, string message, MessageBoxButtons buttons,MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closed += new EventHandler(MessageBoxChildWindow_Closed);

        this.Title = title;
        this.txtMsg.Text = message;
        DisplayButtons(buttons);
        DisplayIcon(icon);
    }

    public enum MessageBoxButtons
    {
        Ok, YesNo, YesNoCancel, OkCancel
    }

    public enum MessageBoxIcon
    {
        Question, Information, Error, None, Warning, Logout, ThankYou
    }

    private void DisplayIcon(MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        switch (icon)
        {
            case MessageBoxIcon.Error:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBox;component/Images/error.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case MessageBoxIcon.Information:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBoxEX;component/Images/Information.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case MessageBoxIcon.Question:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBoxEX;component/Images/SIHIImages/question.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case MessageBoxIcon.Warning:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBoxEX;component/Images/warning.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case MessageBoxIcon.None:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBox;component/Images/Information.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case MessageBoxIcon.Logout:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBoxEX;component/Images/logout1.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;

            case MessageBoxIcon.ThankYou:
                imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/SLMessageBoxEX;component/Images/ThankYou.png", UriKind.Relative));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void DisplayButtons(MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {

        switch (buttons)
        {
            case MessageBoxButtons.Ok:
                btnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnYes.Content = "Ok";
                break;

            case MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel:
                btnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnYes.Content = "Ok";
                break;

            case MessageBoxButtons.YesNo:
                btnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                break;

            case MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel:
                btnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void MessageBoxChildWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnMessageBoxClosed != null)
            OnMessageBoxClosed(this.Result);
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnYes.Content.ToString().ToLower().Equals("yes") == true)
        {
            //yes button
            this.Result = MessageBoxResult.Yes;
        }
        else
        {
            //ok button
            this.Result = MessageBoxResult.OK;
        }

        this.Close();
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

And you can call this Message Box

For Yes No Buttons

```
SLMessageBox messBox;
messBox = new SLMessageBox("Message", "Yes or No Message Box...!", SLMessageBox.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, SLMessageBox.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
messBox.Show();
```

For Only Ok Button

```
SLMessageBox messBox;
messBox = new SLMessageBox("Message", "Ok Message Box...!", SLMessageBox.MessageBoxButtons.Ok, SLMessageBox.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
messBox.Show();
```

For Ok and Cancel Buttons

```
SLMessageBox messBox;
messBox = new SLMessageBox("Message", "Ok and Cancel Message Box...!", SLMessageBox.MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel, SLMessageBox.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
messBox.Show();
```

Edit:
And to check the result of the MessageBox what the user clicked

```
SLMessageBox messBox;
messBox = new SLMessageBox("Message", "Yes, No and Cancel Buttons Message Box...!", SLMessageBox.MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, , SLMessageBox.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
messBox.Show();
messBox.OnMessageBoxClosed += messBox_OnDeleteMessageBoxClosed;

private void messBox_OnDeleteMessageBoxClosed(MessageBoxResult result)
{
   if(result==MessageBoxResult.Yes)
   {
     //....
   }
   else if(result==MessageBoxResult.No)
   {
     //....
   }
   else
   {
     //...
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, can i have three buttons as well ?

Comment: Yes its there in the YesNoCancel buttons.public enum MessageBoxButtons
{
        Ok, YesNo, YesNoCancel, OkCancel
}

Comment: Ok, so it will be SLMessageBox.MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel right ?

Comment: and also can i modify the names Yes,No and  cancel, like custom name ?

Comment: @Goofy I have edited my answer.Yes you can modify button names.

Comment: I need to modify here right :public enum MessageBoxButtons
    {
        Ok, YesNo, YesNoCancel, OkCancel
    }

Comment: This code public enum MessageBoxButtons { Ok, YesNo, YesNoCancel, OkCancel } is used for just what buttons you want to display,you can change names in SLMessageBox.xaml  Button Content property.Go through the code you will get it easily

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50098/discussion-between-goofy-and-nullreferenceexception)

Answer (score 1):

The API only exposes the OK/Cancel. you can use the Coding4Fun MessagePrompt from [Coding4FunToolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) to create Yes/No message:

```
MessagePrompt msgPrompt = new MessagePrompt();
msgPrompt.Message = "Your Message.";
Button yesBtn = new Button() { Content = "Yes" };
yesBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(yesBtn_Click);
Button noBtn = new Button() { Content = "No" };
noBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(noBtn_Click);
msgPrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(noBtn);
msgPrompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Add(yesBtn);
msgPrompt.Show();
```

Comment: Yes i will try it and let you know.

Comment: Which assembly i need use for MessagePrompt ?

Comment: here i have one tick mark button as well as yes and no buttons, how to remove the tick mark button ?

Answer (score 1):

The API only exposes "OK" and "Cancel". If you need to use different button I'm afraid you'll have to use a custom message box.

E.g. http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box/

Answer (score 0):

No, MessageBox is a sealed type.

You will need to make your own MessageBox control, that has "Yes" and "No" buttons.

Comment: Ok, can you show me how to create my own message box?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Guide class from the XNA framework. There is a BeginShowMessageBox method giving you the option to pass in whatever strings you wish for the buttons.

follow following link

[link 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/be8dbf1b-8288-4974-8064-bdd2e1651bc0/how-to-disable-the-sound-and-vibration-in-messageboxshow?forum=wpdevelop)

[link 2](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using)

[link 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Attention!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //this block will be executed when Yes is selected
                MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            else
            {
                //this block will be executed when No is selected
            }
```